# React router not accepting component as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm following a [react redux tutorial](https://github.com/wesbos/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files/tree/master/05) with the app file and main component shown below but I get the error "Invalid prop `component` supplied to `IndexRoute`.    in IndexRoute" and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.

```
//app file


import React from 'react';

import { render } from 'react-dom';


// Import Components
import Main from './components/Main';
import Single from './components/Single';
import PhotoGrid from './components/PhotoGrid';

// import react router deps
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const router = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I read that it might be something to do with the cloneComponent and have tried to replace that part with `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})}` but to no avail.

```
//main

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const Main = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
        </h1>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

export default Main;
```

Comment: try using `{this.props.children}` instead of `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you showed. According to the error message, there is something wrong with your `PhotoGrid` component. Because you do not render the `PhotoGrid` component properly, `react-router` doesn't `PhotoGrid` as a React component. Check your `PhotoGrid` file. To make sure, just copy and paste the code from the source.